# Splitting Data based on requirements

Tags: algorithms

I haven't been able to find a question (or set of questions quite like I am looking for)...apologies if there are.

I am basically trying to figure out how to create an algorithm to "split" muscles between workouts. Here is the main idea:

1) Muscles have "pairs". These are other muscles that work well with another muscle and are recommended to be worked out together.

2) The difference in the number of muscles worked out on each day should be at most 2

3) Try to keep as many pairs together as possible

4) If the number of pairs together, at it's best amount, has several options...then the tiebreaker is to keep the total number of muscle fibers used in each day as close as possible.

I think the following example will help to get the idea across much better:

I have the muscles of: `Quads, Calves, Hamstrings, Glutes and Biceps` that need to be split into two groups.

The pairs of muscles that go together are:

```
Quadriceps <--> Glutes
Calves     <--> Hamstrings
Glutes     <--> Hamstrings
```

For easy logic, we can assume that the number of muscle fibers in each of the muscles is the following:

```
Quadriceps = 75
Glutes = 100
Hamstrings = 50
Calves = 30
Biceps = 30
```

So, knowing this information...I would see that there are several combinations I could make where I keep 2 pairs together:

1) `Quadriceps, Glutes & Hamstrings` on one day, while the other day would be `Biceps & Calves`. This gives muscle fiber counts of 225 to 60

2) `Quadriceps & Glutes` on one day, while the other day would be `Hamstrings, Calves & Biceps`. This gives muscle fiber counts of 175 to 110

With this information, I would like this algorithm to select the second combination.

Does anybody know how I could make this happen? Or at least where to start?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you're dealing with a variation of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).  You may be better off looking for an approximative algorithm rather than a perfect match depending on the size of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Pairs are important: create a complete table of possible pairs. This will make the problem easier and enable a brute force approach. We only do pairs.

Enumerate combinations (of pairs) that make sense. I assume you want to keep the fiber count within some range. Do this in a nested loop for two consecutive days so you get to compair two combinations. Score the pair of combinations and remember the score if it is a top score.